# Set similar divs from 2 columns on one level

Tags: jquery, html, css

On page i have 2 columns : First column has questions and previous answers, while Second has also questions(same questions) and some input fields for answers. This is made for some comparation.

As input fields take some additional space, questions from 2 columns aren't on same level (divs with question from 1st column takes less space then divs with question from 2nd column)

How can i make them be on same level?

I have only one idea - set height for each question block. Is there any other idea?

Thanks.

What i have now :

[image]

Code :

This is main div. Every `CatecoryQuestion` contains some questions.

```
 <div class="row">
       <div id="pnlSubmissionCategoryQuestions" class="col-md-6">...</div>
       <div id="pnlAmendmentCategoryQuestions" class="col-md-6">...</div>
    </div>
```

**http://jsfiddle.net/5vjmtozu/** here is almost full code (please make result form widder to see 2 columns and my problem)

Comment: Post your code please.

Comment: Declare height for a text element is nonsense, you never know what font-size has visitor set in your system. Never set height where you expect text content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to restructure your HTML.  Right now you have one row that encapsulates all of your questions and answers.  You need to have each question/answer and its counterpart on the same row.

Getting some code now.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="submission-question">...</div>
    <div class="amendment-question">...</div>
</div>
```

There's really not much more I can do besides rewrite your code for you.  At this moment, You can't do much with what you have, unless you want some fancy jquery written to give elements the appropriate space.

Comment: ok, i understand what you mean. I just can't figured it out how it will be looks on small screens.

Comment: Have you thought of just using a javascript library to allow people to edit in-line?  If that's not the user scenario, then you'll have to figure something out.  I would suggest rewriting your code to what I kind of show above, then allow the screen size to determine when the amendment shuffles under the submission (or vice versa), so each question has it's admendment and submission on one section

Comment: Well, i done it like you suggest. And for small screens i use .hidden and .vissible classes of Bootstrap to hide (leave just one column as questions are the same) and show (show previously anwers) elements on page

Answer (score 0):

CSS:

```
.row div {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;}
```